# How to fetch Subscription Keys through API Call/HTTP Request for Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, subscriptions

Is there any way to fetch Subscription Keys for Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs through API call/CURL/HTTP request? Currently I have to hard code the keys in my Application to use the services.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  See the List Keys API at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/cognitiveservicesaccounts#CognitiveServicesAccounts_ListKeys.

> POST
>   /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2016-02-01-preview

Which returns JSON:

> {   "key1": "xxxx",   "key2": "xxxxx" }

You can also do this via Powershell using `Get-AzureRmCognitiveServicesAccountKey`

Both of these methods require you to authenticate with the Azure REST API which you can read more about at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/.